# problem showing repeated whole page when trying to display data from database

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to display the data from the database, but whenever I connect it the whole page gets repeated - from the head title to a row and then it shows the head title again as if I had split the page, and another row from the database.

I want to show the data like the products page next to each other but it only shows one and then repeats the whole page.

This is my code that I tried - the page gets repeated from the main-container and shows one row, then repeats the main container again.

```
<?php
require_once 'opp_data.php';
$sql ="SELECT * FROM college_opp";
$allopp =$conn->query($sql);
?>


//i dont know if i have to show the whole code but this is only the code part where everything gets repeated


    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allopp)) {
       
    
    ?>

<div class="main-container">
    <h2>تصفح الفرص التطوعية </h2>

    
        <div class="post-collect">
            <div class="post-main-container">
                    
                            <div class="all sports">
                    <div class="post-img">
                        <img src="imgs/<?php echo $row["images"]; ?>">
                        <span class="category-name" data-name="sporty">كلية علوم الرياضة </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <div class="post-content-top">
                            <span>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-users-line"></i><?php echo  $row["volunteer_num"]; ?>
                            </span>
                <span><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-days"></i><?php echo $row["Date"]; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <h2>"<?php echo $row["Title"]; ?>"</h2>
                        <p>"<?php echo $row["Description"]; ?>"</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="button-btn">
              <a href="#">التفاصيل والتسجيل</a>
                   </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>         
<?php
}
?>


</body>
```

for the style.css\\

```
.main-container{
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0;


}

.main-container h2{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 90px 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;

}

.main-container p{
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
}




.post-main-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 60px;

}
.post-main-container div{
box-shadow: 0px 8px 27px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);


}

.post-img{
  position: relative;
  width: 2vw;
  height: 19vw;


}
.post-img img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 17vw;
  height: 19vw;


}




.post-content{
  padding: 25px;

}

.post-content-top{
  background: #2b1055;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0,9;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
}

.post-content-top span{
  padding-right: 20px;
}




.post-content h2{
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font-weight: 400;

}

.post-content p{
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: ghostwhite;
}
.button-btn a {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  display: block;
  font-family:'Almarai', sans-serif ;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.button-btn a:hover{
  background:#2b1055;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want `<div class="main-container"><h2>تصفح الفرص التطوعية </h2>` to be repeated, then put it outside the loop. Only put inside the loop things which are necessary to repeat.

Comment: The entire page display is inside the `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allopp)) { ... }`. You should first output the header and inside the loop only what you want to display from the database.

Comment: P.S. I would really have hoped it would be self-evident that if there something in your code that you don't want to repeat, you shouldn't put it inside a block of code (such as a loop) whose purpose is to make things repeat.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Because your entire page is in the while loop it will duplicate the whole page multiple times. I don't know if this is exactly what you want but I suggest you doing it something like this:

```
<?php
    require_once 'opp_data.php';
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM college_opp";
    $allopp =$conn->query($sql);
    ?>
  <div class="main-container">
    <h2>تصفح الفرص التطوعية </h2>
    <div class="post-collect">
      <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allopp)) { ?>
      <div class="post-main-container">
        <div class="all sports">
          <div class="post-img">
            <img src="imgs/<?php echo $row[" images "]; ?>">
            <span class="category-name" data-name="sporty">كلية علوم الرياضة </span>
          </div>
          <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-content-top">
              <span>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-users-line"></i><?php echo  $row["volunteer_num"]; ?>
                                </span>
              <span><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-days"></i><?php echo $row["Date"]; ?></span>
            </div>
            <h2>"
              <?php echo $row["Title"]; ?>"</h2>
            <p>"
              <?php echo $row["Description"]; ?>"</p>
          </div>

          <div class="button-btn">
            <a href="#">التفاصيل والتسجيل</a>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>

    </div>
  </div>
```

This will only loop the `post-main-container`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are looking for

```html
<div class="main-container">
   <h2>تصفح الفرص التطوعية </h2>
     <div class="post-collect">
       <div class="post-main-container"> 
       <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allopp)) {
       ?>
        <div class="all sports">
          <div class="post-img">
             <img src="imgs/<?php echo $row["images"]; ?>">
             <span class="category-name" data-name="sporty">كلية علوم الرياضة </span>
          </div>
          <div class="post-content">
             <div class="post-content-top">
               <span>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-users-line"></i><?php echo  $row["volunteer_num"]; ?>
               </span>
               <span>
               <i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-days"></i><?php echo $row["Date"]; ?>
               </span>
             </div>
             <h2>"<?php echo $row["Title"]; ?>"</h2>
             <p>"<?php echo $row["Description"]; ?>"</p>
          </div>

          <div class="button-btn">
            <a href="#">التفاصيل والتسجيل</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
            
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```